# ServiceStack MVC 3+ examples

Tags: c#, servicestack

I've been taking a look at ServiceStack and it looks amazing. Although I'm not fully understanding how all of the components work together. Is there a full best practices example somewhere available? I've been Googling for a while now :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @scottm mentions the [online documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki) and the [Example Projects](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/) containing the source code for all the [online demos](http://www.servicestack.net/) and [Starter Templates](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/tree/master/src/StarterTemplates) are a good starting point especially the [Creating your first web service](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Create-your-first-webservice) documentation page which takes you through creating a new ServiceStack project from scratch using only the [ServiceStack NuGet binaries](http://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack).

For a **Big Picture** solution you should also check out the **[Social Bootstrap Api](https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi)** demo project which contains a complete ServiceStack + MVC + Backbone.js Single Page App using Twitters Bootstrap website template. It optionally makes use of many of ServiceStack's components and AuthProviders which should give you a good feel how all the parts fit together.

Answer (score 3):

The docs are [pretty extensive](http://www.servicestack.net/docs/framework/overview)...

I suggest downloading the [sample projects](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/downloads), read the documentation and following [this tutorial](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/) to get you a full idea. If you still don't understand at that point, maybe another, more simple, framework would be better for you.